# js object only partially getting passed to controller

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller, asp.net-ajax

I am submitting a js object via ajax to the controller.  3 of the 4 children that I am passing are passing correctly.  Can anyone tell why the 4th (Action) is null in the controller?

It appears correctly when debugging the js.
[image]

But is null when stepping into the controller.
[image]

Object, Post, Subject are passed correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Failed locally for me as well, I know for sure "Action" is not some sort of js or c# reserved word... Changing the model property name to something like "Action1" (and also in the js object) did the trick. Odd!

Comment: I too was thinking it has something to do with the word `Action`, couldn't find any documentation about the word though.